# Protecting a soldering hot plate with thermal fuse

Tags: relay, fuses, solid-state-relay, thermal

I am DIYing a reflow soldering hot plate, with an SSR allowing to regulate the hot plate temperature. However, I understand that SSRs can sometimes fail closed, which basically means that this would risk damaging the PCB and the components. I read that a good way of protecting the whole system is by using a thermal fuse, but I'm unsure about how the whole thing is supposed to work out.

Basically, the thermal fuse is supposed to fail whenever its temperature rises above a threshold; this means that the thermal fuse should be kept close to the heating plate, such that its temperature is close to the one of the plate and can then fail before the plate temperature goes too high, is this right? This means anyway that the temperature of the fuse will always be quite below the high point of the hot plate, therefore how should the fail temp of the fuse be chosen? Should the fuse be sticked to the plate with thermal paste? How should the fuse be held in place, are there some wrappings to put the fuse in?

Actually, I am even wondering whether this is an actual good solution to the problem. I am monitoring the temperature anyway, so would using a classic mechanical relay, normally closed, that opens whenever the monitored temperature raises too high compared to the target temperature (which would mean something failing) be an actual solution to the "failed close SSR" potential issue?

Comment: Can you choose a temperature fuse just above your desired value + some margin?

Comment: What power heater are you using?

Comment: A thermal fuse is probably better used as protection against a failure causing damage to the heating plate  or causing a fire, if that failure consequence is a possibility. How much over-temperature will you consider acceptable before you trash the PCB ?

Answer (score 0):

Must admit if I was asked to create this circuit as a hobby project I would be looking at a cheap Chinese PID module which includes an SSR and alarms. Here is some [introductory PID text](https://au.rs-online.com/web/content/discovery/ideas-and-advice/pid-temperature-controllers-guide). If this is for a piece of expensive equipment then look for a high quality branded module (that may also be Chinese).

A fuse has the advantage of absolute circuit protection and prevents continued operation. Catch is they may have to be in contact with the heated vessel. Usually they are painful to replace. A thermostat may be a suitable alternative. An Overtemperature alarm could be wired up to blow a fuse. There are many possibilities.

Alternatively there are [Reflow Oven](https://www.siliconchip.com.au/Issue/2020/April/A+DIY+Reflow+Oven+Controller+for+modern+soldering) projects with PID control.